# In Estjs TestField 'X' button does not appear in Chrome browser but its appear in IE

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, user-interface, internet-explorer

when I write input on my search Textfield the ClearText 'X' button does not appear in chrome browser but it appears in IE browser.
I am using Estjs.
Here are the pic.

[image: picture IE browser]

want 'x' in chrome browser